# ROS installation on ARCH LINUX : qt or shiboken error

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

I tried to install ROS JADE on my new arch linux machine via AUR repos using yaourt
and I can't even understand the error. sure something in python maybe a dependency related to qt
but I am not able to understand what it is. See the screenshot
the command I use is

> yaourt --noconfirm ros-jade-desktop

Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245367/ros-installation-on-arch-linux-:--qt-or-shiboken-error/) by [Dexter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28197/dexter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:
Please don't use images to show us what is essentially text. Copy/paste from your terminal into your question, then format the console text using the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it). Images are not searchable, reducing the visibility of this question (in Google fi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is "No such file or directory" And it's trying to invoke qmake. I would guess that qmake is not installed on your system.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0